# How to add Configuration of Google Analytics / Firebase in MVC Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, firebase, asp.net-mvc-3, google-analytics

I am quite new to `Google Analytics/Firebase`. I am trying to configure `Google Analytics/Firebase` to my `MVC Application`. I have used [Firebase Analytics Official Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/get-started?platform=web) but I stuck at step 1. So what have I done so far is I have created Firebase Project and enabled Analytics in it , Docs provide implementation through `npm` for other type of projects they have just provided a `script`
Now I don't know where should I add that `script` in my `MVC application` so it could be used for all project.